# How to change the size of a bitmap contained in an ImageView without affecting surrounding view's position in Android?

Tags: android

I have an ImageView that contains a bitmap. Now the bitmap can change size within a known range. This makes the surrounding views to relocate which I want to prevent. I've tried setting margins and padding for the ImageView but without success. Any ideas?
Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your ImageView and other UI elements into a FrameLayout and setting each item's android:layout_gravity to place them.

Comment: FrameworkLayout didn't solve the problem unfortunately. I sort of fixed it though by changing the size of the view to the same of the bitmap. The downside is that the image rescales when rotated but that I can live with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
imageView = new ImageView(context)
{
     @Override
     protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
     {
         setMeasuredDimension(knownMaxWidth, knownMaxHeight);

     }
};

imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```

Comment: This appears to keep the image intact. The question seems to be about the layout around the image, not the image itself.